# portqry to check connectivity

Tags: scripting, powershell, batch

Is it possible to check the connectivity between 2 remote servers using portqry given that the portqry.exe command is executed on another server. for example, check the connectivity  between serverA and serverB where the portqry.exe command is running on serverC

Also please advise what is best solution/way to automated this

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

No. However, you if have portqry on ServerA you can use PowerShell remoting from ServerC to ServerA and portqry against ServerB, achieving what (I'm guessing) you're asking for.

Your question is fairly vague.